# Restricting Cassandra to localhost only

Tags: cassandra, localhost

I installed cassandra as a service on Ubuntu. Test Cluster is accessible on 127.0.0.1:9042. I want to restrict everything related to cassandra to localhost only, nothing open to internet. Currently, this is what I see on `netstat -tulpen`:

```
udp        0      0 130.159.223.50:123      0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 fe80::215:5dff:fcdf:123 :::*
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: What you want to achieve can be done through configuration, but for a production cluster, it should be done using a firewall.

You need to modify a number of settings in cassanra.yaml to listen only for the loopback address (127.0.0.1)

```
listen_address: 127.0.0.1
rpc_address: 127.0.0.1
# make sure the broadcast address is commented out
# broadcast_address: 1.2.3.4
```

When running nodetool you should see the node's ip as the loopback interface ip

```
$ nodetool  status

Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  60.62 TB   256          ?       e7060cda-f99b-495c-ad55-2d380b4d452e  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership 
information is meaningless
```

You can then verify that cassandra is innacessable over the public or private ip but only on the loopback ip with telnet:

```
core:cassandra core$ telnet <external ip> 9042
Trying 134.103.x.x...
telnet: connect to address 134.103.x.x: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

core:cassandra core$ telnet <internal ip> 9042
Trying 10.17.x.x...
telnet: connect to address 10.17.x.x: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

core:cassandra core$ telnet 127.0.0.1 9042
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
```